# How to I check what the php environment variables are currently set to on AWS EB?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

How can I check what the PHP environment variables below are currently set to on my AWS EB (Elastic Beanstalk) instance?

upload_max_filesize = 
post_max_size = 
memory_limit =
max_execution_time =
max_input_time =

Answer (score 0):

You can login to the instance with the command `eb ssh`. This will temporary open port 22 and login to the instance via ssh.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/eb3-ssh.html

Now you can check or update your php.ini file.

You can also create a page or run `phpinfo()` from command line:

`php -r 'echo phpinfo();'`